# Instrument cluster malfunction

Tags: toyota, camry, gauges

On a 2007 Camry why does the instrument panel work properly and suddenly goes haywire and all guages shut down but the car continues running fine. What's going on?

Comment: gauges only? do you lose illumination or the odometer?

Comment: Just gauges quit working. Illumination stays on.

Comment: Bad fuse? Maybe that is the issue since all the sensors can’t have stopped working at exactly the same time

Comment: Or relay ^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: That was my original thoughts, but usually when a fuse or relay goes bad the instrument that the fuse leads to quits working permanently. But that's not the case here. Each time the car is started the guages work properly, but after a few minutes they all go crazy for a second and just shut down completely until next time the car is driven.

Comment: Having same issue with 2010 Toyota Camry SE? Any updates?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a known issue with the 2007 Toyota Camry. Here is a list of [consumer complaints to the NHTSA](http://www.thesafetyinstitute.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/05_2007toyotacamry_speedcontrol.pdf).

First, call the Dealership, give them your VIN and ask if there are any recalls outstanding for your car related to this issue.

The post I have seen one the **[Camry Forum](https://www.camryforums.com/forum/general-tech-8/2007-camry-instrumentation-ghost-39934/)** indicate this is caused by a failed ABS module. The dealer will want a lot of money to replace it, but it is a simple replacement you can do yourself.

Here is a **[site](https://modulemaster.com/rebuilds/shop/brakes/abs-modules/toyota-camry-2007-2009-8-1/)** that sells the part rebuilt. Even lists this as fixing the exact things you described.

[image]

Comment: I can see how that might cause OPs complaint. OP should verify that there is communication with the Combination Meter when this occurs and if there is check for data inputs like VSS and RPM. OP should probably also pin drag the combination meter connector. If this is a communication issue there should be U codes logged in relevant modules.